# Extract query value from URL

Tags: java, url

I have following URL:
`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.bandainamcoent.verylittlenightmares&hl=en";`

I want to extract this value: `eu.bandainamcoent.verylittlenightmares`

```
URI uri = new URI(URL);
uri.getQuery();
```

I'll get this: `id=eu.bandainamcoent.verylittlenightmares&hl=en`

How to cut `id=` and `&hl=en`?
And `&hl=en` may not exist and can be different, like `&hl=de` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no function in URI to do this, but here is a trick to solve it:

```
Map<String, String> params = Arrays.stream(uri.getQuery().split("&"))
        .map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k[0], v -> v.length > 1 ? v[1] : ""));
String id = params.get("id"); // eu.bandainamcoent.verylittlenightmares
String hl = params.get("hl"); // en
```

We are sure that the only separator between two parameters is `&`, and the parameter have a name and value separated by `=`, for that you split with `&`, and for each result split with `=`, and the result is a Map which contain the param name as key and value as value.