# Best practice of getting parameters from URI?

Tags: java, parameters, uri

I am given one of two request URIs, and I do not know which one I will receive:

```
/?code=someAuthorizationCode&state=someState
/?error=someError&state=someState
```

I have used `String[] redirectURIQueryParameters = exchange.getRequestURI().toString().split("[?/&]+");` to get the parameters and their corresponding values. Printing the string by ascending index results in an empty string, and then either `code=someAuthorizationCode` or `error=someError`, and then `state=someState`.

I understand that it is possible to determine the parameters returned and their corresponding values from the second string of the array onwards, but I am sure there is a cleaner way of doing so. What is the most efficient method of extracting the parameters from these URIs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683432/extract-query-value-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Map as your parameter in your Controller and you will get them as key-value pairs.